# How to overload function in TypeScript with optional parameters?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code that is partly converted to TypeScript (from JavaScript).

Basically if a `callback` parameter exists, I always want the function itself to return `void`. Otherwise, return type `Promise<object>`. With an optional parameter (`settings`) before that (so technically the `callback` parameter could be passed in as the `settings` parameter, which the first few lines of the function handle that use case).

For backwards compatibility purposes (and to keep code DRY), I do not want to create another function called `savePromise` or `saveCallback` and separate it out. I'm trying to figure out how to get TypeScript to be smart enough to understand this logic somehow.

```js
type CallbackType<T, E> = (response: T | null, error?: E) => void;

class User {
    save(data: string, settings?: object, callback?: CallbackType<object, string>): Promise<object> | void {
        if (typeof settings === "function") {
            callback = settings;
            settings = undefined;
        }

        if (callback) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                callback({"id": 1, "settings": settings});
            }, 1000);
        } else {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve({"id": 1, "settings": settings});
                }, 1000);
            });
        }
    }
}

const a = new User().save("Hello World"); // Should be type Promise<object>, should eventually resolve to {"id": 1, "settings": undefined}
const b = new User().save("Hello World", (obj) => {
    console.log(obj); // {"id": 1, "settings": undefined}
}); // Should be type void
const c = new User().save("Hello World", {"log": true}); // Should be type Promise<object>, should eventually resolve to {"id": 1, "settings": {"log": true}}
const d = new User().save("Hello World", {"log": true}, (obj) => {
    console.log(obj); // {"id": 1, "settings": {"log": true}}
}); // Should be type void
```

I'm pretty sure the type file I'm aiming for would be something along the lines of the following. Not sure I'm accurate here tho.

```
save(data: string, settings?: object): Promise<object>;
save(data: string, callback: CallbackType<object, string>): void;
save(data: string, settings: object, callback: CallbackType<object, string>): void;
```

It seems like the `callback` parameter being passed in as the `settings` parameter use case can be handled by doing something like:

```
save(data: string, settings?: object | CallbackType<object, string>, callback?: CallbackType<object, string>): Promise<object> | void
```

But that is super messy, and from my experience it doesn't seem like TypeScript is smart enough to realize that `settings` will always be an optional object after those first 4 lines of code in the function. Which means when calling `callback` you have to type cast it, which again, feels really messy.

How can I achieve this with TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Here's the solution (with some refactoring):

```js
type CallbackType<T, E> = (response: T | null, error?: E) => void;
interface ISettings {
  log?: boolean;
}
interface ISaveResult {
  id: number;
  settings: ISettings | undefined;
}

class User {
  save(data: string): Promise<ISaveResult>;
  save(data: string, settings: ISettings): Promise<ISaveResult>;
  save(data: string, callback: CallbackType<ISaveResult, string>): void;
  save(data: string, settings: ISettings, callback: CallbackType<ISaveResult, string>): void;
  save(data: string, settings?: ISettings | CallbackType<ISaveResult, string>, callback?: CallbackType<ISaveResult, string>): Promise<ISaveResult> | void {
    if (typeof settings !== "object" && typeof settings !== "undefined") {
      callback = settings;
      settings = undefined;
    }

    const localSettings = settings; // required for closure compatibility
    if (callback) {
      const localCallback = callback; // required for closure compatibility
      setTimeout(() => {
        localCallback({ id: 1, "settings": localSettings });
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve({ id: 1, "settings": localSettings });
        }, 1000);
      });
    }
  }
}

const a = new User().save("Hello World"); // User.save(data: string): Promise<ISaveResult>

const b = new User().save("Hello World", obj => { 
  console.log(obj); // obj: ISaveResult | null
}); // User.save(data: string, callback: CallbackType<ISaveResult, string>): void

const c = new User().save("Hello World", { "log": true }); // User.save(data: string, settings: ISettings): Promise<ISaveResult>

const d = new User().save("Hello World", { "log": true }, (obj) => {
  console.log(obj); // obj: ISaveResult | null
}); // User.save(data: string, settings: ISettings, callback: CallbackType<ISaveResult, string>): void
```

see [code pan](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=47&pc=103#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgGwQIzgYwNYBVwQDxYA0UAogHxQC8UAFAE4QDOYA9gHaMQBcUWUAPlDYBXJMQh06LOgH4eJAJRUKANxYBLACYBuAFDq2wCQDN00AJIBlCMGAGA5oygBvXVCgIW9uVGQsWCBBwbHoAvvqGJmZQVnAqEABKTKLALm5QWjwiALbIEnrunLYOjDxWNnZsjgJQwmyaEMYGEDq64bpoCHCMTgCqnHRphXEQNJpwwHA8jMB0Dgo8AApS2eqceLHxSYwpZAVQjCNjE1MHsw7ERZWOZdbFVYwLUMssq%20ubickIwHvph-HHSbTc5VYhoRAodAYHjwJCoTA4SAbSwjbYpS4g%20xkJ5qLT7f6jcZAs5zUEHColW4Uh5giHw6GwOlQxH4D5o74Y0lYnEaVrDAFE04zLmXamOHzle7VQSwyEI3DI1FfYCchxkWlwqE%20WX0lmKrbK1VVbFLFZrVkog07b4UQS4zRDdwZYy0UCQFguq4lKAAQko1AARCxkAArCBoYABqAAMmjUDdEA95KlTj9gbqDSabBaAaUridTvBmswVGT10Y%20wLXoepYzjWafKd7QLaHYMw8LCLd3Lperjm0UAA9IOoAwAI7CdQMB3GaRQTosHYMeevMATdTIdQIdSgdLudQumhFuUYPN7wtt1KeIs6qGl4-0gfD0cQCdTlpQWeDBdL6Ct7JrnYm7bruBaFDYWDqNkibCMANA0EolAUPmYHuNeiC3pgNDOBkmg8AAjMQAZ9owAY8OhCDdt6oQKJWTbEPhAAMzG0eeoRQBACCcI6BYMMAwh0GwQgQAA7s8ZqcPBDCMAE8SIch55VhBUEwXBCHKDxqEvjJCAAjhmRQIRUDEWKpHkZ2iBUTWNF0QWoQMcxjGsahNlsek4TtK2HCpHApbZmJ-QSAhAB0BI0AGAASnGeFAADq0gIJouZPiONDQcAAAWLCaEogV0KFRyCsCXJPC8bwWkq1o-LoHSXr4fmiVAeUhWFkXRSwcUJUlxDBiGGk4ekXk6RAwWePYNC9bRQ4jr1tyVSkNQiEgbRTc%20eUFQKJzFRc85MpgMJ7dgCpsoaJJqjyWg1UNqRoA1AUDC1RxtUgHXxXQiUBsQOEBmNZHxnQwjQDZ020OlWU5U1AwbYSW1nWSJFUimpUSRVVq7FddUOtQ-mQ0FCjQ%20FUUvZ173dS4xm-TwsyA1A9m0JN-WDW2AQjWNE2hqtM2hnNaPfItogICtKW4-lYVFXD9iiimiPlhqJ4HcWR1IidVVGtyPD2kAA)

### Explanation

a `Function` is an `Object` as well, so TypeScript was not able to implicitly distinguish between the two. By creating a specific `ISettings` interface, you allow TypeScript to distinguish between a settings object and a callback function.

The easiest way to see that is look at the errors TypeScript puts out and the types of the variables as the code flow progresses, e.g. ([your code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=31&pc=27#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgGwQIzgYwNYBVwQDxYA0UAogHxQC8UAFAE4QDOYA9gHaMQBcUWUAPlDYBXJMQh06LOgH4eJAJRUKANxYBLACYBuAFC60COI0ZQAqpzpQA3rqj2ojOCog1NcYHB6NgddWwBzYk5gYH8AxjkoFmQAKwg0YGI0RBR0DCj4JFRMHEg8GPjE4N9wsgUeAAUpAFt1TgK4hOAKQTUtGzsHbvUAM1pQSBZ%20kLDA00pJqAAiXuE2RPV2aaVbbvWHFOz0qkcIUPDGPQ2N0cPd%20c0IXv8IHS6NgF99E6g%202i20zFWH173gLDqGoQFjCYA0GhKSgUNZ-DafHIYGjWaZaaY8ACMxGmZ3G6P%20YwijwUxzhUEexAxAAYaSTft1HlAIAhOJ0yVAGMBhHQ2EIIAB3KDVFh1TgQhiMFgIFxQmH0skhQHA0HgyHKNnsk4SqUuZGozT4rEzXERfEmxjE0ma8mUmlUunsy3y%20zPBm6Z4Gdg%20KBwXZsAXmSyQgB0Tl10wAEsyECwoAB1aQIA0kqAAelTUAAygALUFJqDIaCDaDC0X4QrNMjBXOiTRMlxsLmpEAcpg6ouxlFozHY834y7XW6aZ5oL3AAt%20gMWCQhsOuSPR2MJuhJ6bEGiFWUa%20yjjhSiDBmMBDdxFPpmz6w29-aExj9thXG7%204fus8ZnN5uuFqDFqDtTSehw45oJOgrTnQs7OPOUZIEuiYGsQKJHvivjCBAlppu%20Nb5t%20v6lvU5ZNIkVaONhdYQA2TZIC22rSh2F7dlARo4jehz4khLABChdBoY8I5jlAdbUP6YFBgooZQTQC6wfG8FrheyE8Kh6Hrpu6qwjuXr7oenEnrEb4MQaPbGqxeI8BxXFKTx6HPBh54frWBZFrgf4aJoQA)):

- When hovering over `settings` in `if` condition:

  [image]
- When hovering over `settings` inside `if` block:

  [image]
- `callback` assignment error:

  > Type 'Function' is not assignable to type 'CallbackType'.
  >   Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(response: object | null, error?: string | undefined): void'.(2322)

Comment: This was super helpful. I think the biggest thing that I didn't understand was putting multiple method definitions like that. Does the order of those method definitions matter? And, can you please elaborate on `required for closure compatibility`? I don't understand the purpose of those 2 lines.

Comment: The order does not matter. The closure comment is due to how closures work in JavaScript. see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures
Need to make sure the variable doesn't change when the callback scope is executed.

Comment: Which section is relevant to this specific thing on that link?

Comment: I believe `Creating closures in loops: A common mistake`, not a 100% sure about the implications, but the TypeScript engine warns about it otherwise. You can try without it and see what the error is.